# Viewport not showing models

Tags: 3d-view

The Models are not appearing and only being visible from a perspective. I'm not able to see them. Please help.[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi S_Hello, i know you are new here and it is your first question, so i try to be respectful: we are no magicians, just a little bit more experienced Blender users. It is not like in a garage where they repair your car because they can see and check your car, because you didn't show us your car at all - you just showed one snapshot (photograph) of your car. Do you think the guy of the garage could help you know just with the information of one photo? So please provide blend file so we can see what you did. thx.

Comment: pls read https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask and improve your question, thx.

Comment: Apologies, now I have added more details and images for others to understand it better.

Comment: Yes, thank you. It solved the issue.